# Loading large amount of data from Sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary, load

I'm writing an Android application that has different parts, including a dictionary. To implement a dictionary, I used the following technique:

1. Reading all words from Sqlite database and storing them in array list. ("select * from vocabulary").
2. Searching for definitions, using a simple binary search on array list.

It takes too long to fetch words from database (about 50000 words) and some times it gives "out of memory" exception. However after loading data, it works very rapidly to find definition of words.
Would you please guide me how I can implement the dictionary?

Answer (score 4):

Databases are typically meant for quick out of memory access (disk access). Taking your entire database and putting it into memory doesn't make much sense. Use sql to access only the information you need for the particular task. Make your index on the lookup key for performance

Comment: +1, I am actually amazed by how quick queries are on Android using SQLite, even complex queries. I am now using the database as my main memory for most of my applications (reading from it when I need information, saving to it as soon as the user enters some input)

Comment: As a sidenote, this is true BECAUSE the database is local - when there is a network between the database server and the application server, it then makes sense to "cache" the data locally in memory. This is not the case in Android, obviously.

Comment: Actually I want to give user the real time definitions. On the other hand, there is editText that has a TextWatcher. I have to fetch data from database when the text of editText changes. Do you still think it's good idea to use database, or using an array list? Please help me.

Comment: Thank you. Your idea has been implemented and works well. Thanks.